# Помогите решить задание. Python

Tags: python

Дана непустая последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем. Найти: а) сумму всех чисел последовательности; б) количество всех чисел последовательности
Решить задачу используя циклическую конструкцию while.
Не могу понять, что значит "Дана непустая последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем." и как оформить её через цикл while

Comment: Что-то это на просьбу о помощи непохоже, так - забацайте за меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
i = 0
c = 0
a = len(arr)
while a > 0:
    i += arr[a - 1]
    c += 1
    a -= 1
print(i)
print(c)
```

Comment: Это неправильный ответ